# Issue related to Kentico on-line form (bizform) validation

Tags: kentico

I have created a form using Kentico on-line form and applied the built-in "required" validation on it. Whenever a textbox is empty then a required validation is shown. Now, I have entered a value in the textbox and press tab from the keyboard but the required message does not disappear. I want to remove or hide the message from the form when the user enters a value in the text box before the submit button is clicked.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: As long as I remember Kentico on-line forms do not support client side validation. On my projects I use custom client-side validation for this purpose. e.g. angular-validation

Comment: Thanks, I have used javascript validation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall this being something that Kentico handles out-of-the-box.  You'll most likely need to add some custom client-side script for this.  Typically - where I work, at [Ridgeway](http://www.ridgeway.net) - we use custom layouts for forms, as the standard layout is fairly table-rich.